# What project management software would you guys recommend?

Tags: untagged

I need a project management software to manage my web development projects, the designers are sending me too many updates and changes on the content and overall design and I need to implement a way to setup deadlines in order to finish the projects properly and on time, the only one I know and have used in the past is Microsoft Project, is there any other I should consider review?

Thanks.

EDIT: after a little research, i think my problem needs to be solved with Version Control software, I will close this case, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: This is something I would post of Stackoverflow.com which is a sister site to serverfault but thats for programmers we may be better able to help you there.

Comment: i thought stackoverflow was more into programming than actual system administration which is what i think my question is about.

Comment: But project management is very programming related, in my experience projects management is more programming then server admin.

Comment: In fact i think that this would be better at Super User, that is about software and how to use it. Not IT or development. I would recomend here Microsoft Project. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is for managing software projects, you may want to try [Lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/). Full featured, yet easy to get started with and use.

If that's not gonna fit the bill, give [BaseCamp](http://www.basecamphq.com/) a try. [37Signals](http://37signals.com/) originally developed it to manage their design business.

Answer (score 6):

It's been a while since I looked at the demo, but FogBugz (from StackOverflow/ServerFault co-founder Joel Spolsky) is worth considering.

Comment: +1 I highly recommend it. It is extremely easy to use and very intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Did you look at this [List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_project_management_software)?

That should contain enough information to help you get started!

Comment: yes, but i need recommendations from people that is actually using them to narrow my review possibilities, or i will never be able to decide and will end up just using the standard ms project.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a process for project management rather than a peice of software.

Remember software is a tool that will help support a process.

Sorry if this sound like sucking eggs, but its for those that find it later =>

[Software Development Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process)  can be also known as Software Development Life Cycle - SDLC.

You describing symptoms of scope creep and revisions to existing scope. 
However to cut a long journey down - there a pros and cons to various methods of helping acheive a balance of the views in this "war". (it feels like that sometimes)

The argument is -

> "I have constant changes - I need a
>   specification that the customer and
>   team can design and build too. The
>   "line in the sand or stake in the ground" as trying to build
>   on quicksand is hard and costly."
>   [the classic waterfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process#Waterfall_processes)

Versus

> "The spec is outdated and no longer
>   reflects reality and my customer
>   and team will be un-happy and the customer wont pay me."

In come the trendy new kids on the block - AKA [RAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development),  [Agile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development), [XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process#XP:_Extreme_Programming) and [Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development))

The idea is, as you are seeing - changes in the scope costs and inordinate amount of money to change - compared with the any upfront investment in clear static requirements.
  The "war" is actually not about the need for requirements to be solid - just the time it takes to compile them.  Each has their own views.

Hence the software you will see is often in support of one of the methods.

For a general link to 
[Project Management Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management)

Answer (score 4):

It is also worth looking at Trac (http://trac.edgewall.org/), which is essentially an integrated SCM & Project management tool. It comes with a wiki, issue tracker and can also integrate with a variety of version control systems.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [dotProject](http://www.dotproject.net/) it works great and is free.

Answer (score 2):

I had this question recently myself. After much research, i decided to go with [ActiveCollab](http://www.activecollab.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a pain in the backside I'd stick with MS Project as you're familiar with it and it's 'the default' for most people in the way MS Excel/Word/PowerPoint is so you'll be able to deal with other people's files easily. Whether it's the best fit for you is a different matter but I'd suggest that even if it's not just the familiarity and interoperability would tip it towards MS Project for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Intervals](http://www.myintervals.com). It was built by a web development agency to address the exact issues you've described in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try Trac, Unfuddle or RedMine. All three are project management apps (or services) that integrate TIGHTLY with Version Control, that way you can set deadlines and assign tasks, as well as provide a much safer way to integrate their changes into the project.